# What Could be the Problem of Access Salesforce Object Using Simple Salesforce?

Tags: python, rest, salesforce, simple-salesforce

I'm trying to update an Account record in my Account object at Salesforce.
I initialized the instance using the syntax:

```
sf = Salesforce(username=sf_username, password=sf_psd, security_token=sf_stoken)
```

I verified that it works by exporting a report, but when I tried the syntax of:

`sf.Account.update(unique_RecordID, record_to_update)`

It won't run. I tried
`sf.Account.describe()` to see whether I have an access to the object but it won't run as well.
This syntax worked for me half a year ago, when I wrote the code.
Any suggestions what happened?

Thx!